# "sudo mv /fromdir /todir" - not recognizing the fromdir location

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

I'm trying to get a small folder (/test) with a couple small text files to a folder that I don't have write permissions for. I'm the sole user on this account and I don't know why I wouldn't have access.

My first attempt was to use the gui to create a folder but it is not a selectable option when I right click.  When I look at the permissions for the folder I want to place my new folder it it the root's and in the root group.

I then tried writing the folder in the terminal which worked.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/shiny-server/test
```

So I tried writing the files to the folder but it seems there are many ways to do this and I am confused on what to do.  Assume I want to write a very simple text file that might have quotes, less than symbols and other characters in it.

Then I thought the easiest solution might be to just move a directory over using the command line.

```
sudo mv /Home/Documents/test opt/shiny-server/
```

But there is "no such directory" for test folder even though I can see it in the gui.

So this is a call for help to learn ubuntu...

1. I want to know how can I change the permission on this folder to write files and folders.
2. What is the best way to write text file in a single instance in terminal using a cut paste approach?
3. What is wrong with my method for trying to move folders?

Thanks! Working with 12.04 here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please don't post multiple queries as a single question, break them up into separate ones. The `not found` issue is because you used `opt/shiny-server` instead of `/opt/shiny-server`. The rest are to broad to answer, they will depend on your particular use scenario. As a general rule however, you should not touch anything in `/opt` unless you know what you're doing. If you want to play with things, do it in your home directory.

Comment: what is /Home/Documents? did you mean /home/$USER/Documents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `mv` command you are using a relative path for `opt/shiny-server/` so this will only work if you current directory has opt as a subdirectory. To ensure that this isn't the issue use a full path `/opt/shiny-server/`.

To change permission of `/opt/shiny-server/test/` use `sudo chmod 777 /opt/shiny-server/test` This opens up the permissions for everyone.

A better solution is to change the permission to give You more access `sudo chown <username>:<username> /opt/shiny-server/test/`

To work with files with strange characters in the name, wrap the filename in quotes, and escape single and double quote within the name `"this<>isn\'t aNICE file.name"`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the difference between absolute and relative path. So `opt/shiny-server/` is not the same as `/opt/shiny-server/` ; the first starts in the current directory and the second starts at root or /

Same problem with `test` and `/test`

See http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html